# findIndex() returns -1 even though item exists in the Array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Here is a part of the function I'm working on:

`this.instructions` is an array.

I've deliberately added some console.log() just to show you that the item I'm looking for in `this.instructions` array exists.

```
insertOrUpdateI(i, instruction_frame) {

    if (i.hasOwnProperty('src_id')) {
      let iToUpdateIndex = this.instructions.findIndex(known_i => known_i.src_id == i.src_id);
      console.log('i: ',i)
      console.log('this.instructions: ',this.instructions);
      console.log('iToUpdateIndex: ', iToUpdateIndex);
      if (iToUpdateIndex > -1) {
        let oldInstruction = this.instructions[iToUpdateIndex];
        this.instructions[iToUpdateIndex] = {...i, frame: oldInstruction.frame}; // don't update the frame
        this.reconstructMatchState({
          fetchFromBack: false,
          lastFrame: this.stream.lastCameraFrame,
          applyNow: true
        }).subscribe();
        return
      }
    }
....
```

Here is the result I get:

> i : {subject: "card", player_id: 6547, card_type: "yellow_card", src_id: 1, frame: 5077}
>
> this.instructions: [{subject: "period", name: "period_1", start: 5031, frame: 5031, src_id: -1},
> {subject: "card", player_id: 6547, card_type: "yellow_card", src_id: 1, frame: 5077}]
>
> iToUpdateInde: -1

However, I have i.src_id === 1 and there is an item on my array that has a src_id == 1

What am I missing? I would appreciate some help!

Comment: `iToUpdateIndex = this.instructions.indexOf(i)` would work better.

Comment: works fine for me - https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-qmmf9e

Comment: @trichetriche no it would not.

Comment: @JonasWilms why not ?

Comment: `iToUpdateInde` indicates to me that the logs youve shown do not match tue code youve shown. [mcve] please.

Comment: @JonasWilms oh, my bad, I thought `findIndex` was just a typo from a copy/paste of another language. But it indeed [exists](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/findIndex)

Comment: @trichetriche when I do what you have suggested, my whole stops working as expected, and it doesn't work either!

Comment: @trichetriche What about objects? `[{ foo: "bar" }].indexOf({ foo: "bar"}) == -1`.

Comment: @JackBashford that's not the case here, is it ?

Answer (score 0):

Works for me [here's a stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-twamus?file=src/app/app.component.ts), try doing another ng serve.

Comment: I did a new ng serve, and I sent 2 instructions, for the first one I got iToUpdateInde == -1 and for the second one I got iToUpdateInde == 1.

Comment: oh, that's weird, I think that should be due to an async call then! check if the instructions array or i it self is retrieved from a Http call, the first one could have failed because it was performed before response is received fromthe http call.

Comment: try doing the console.log() before and after the findIndex() to see your data

Comment: so I did the logs correspond exactly to the data I have

Comment: and still it's outputting a wrong answer? and the second findIndex() is right? strange

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I've found an answer to my question here: 
[Is console.log async or sync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23392111/console-log-async-or-sync)
There was nothing wrong with my code, the problem may have come from the version of developer tools I was using.

It seems that console.log() have different behaviors according to the browser we're using and it's version. And sometimes it may have an asynchronous behavior, even though we aren't passing any callbacks inside of it!